# Nice book on geometry to gift an undergraduate in mathematics

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I would like some suggestions on a nice book on geometry to gift an undergraduate. I'm not searching for something that is common: I need something new and exciting. Suggestions?

Comment: There are better gifts for an undergraduate than a book on mathematics :)

Comment: I am not exactly sure what an undergraduate is - I don't know the American education system that well, but I like "The symmetries of things" by Conway et al.

Comment: @LordSoth: Glen Livet 25?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I would take it for sure, but an undergrad would waste it. Heineken $10^3$-pack would be a better option.

Comment: @LordSoth: I wouldn't touch Heineken with a poking stick, even before my undergrad years. But my Glen Livet 18 made it through my undergrad without worries, with only the occasional drink.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Haha. I am curious as to how did you manage not to devour the entire bottle during one of those heartache days (almost sure to happen in 4 years of undergrad). I commend your command on your ethanol.

Comment: @LordSoth: (1) Three years of undergrad; (2) Cheap arak, and homemade lemoncello with insane proof strength. Also, lots of beer. Great scotch is saved for great occasions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I love [this one](http://www.maa.org/publications/books/new-horizons-in-geometry). It is one of the most stimulating books on geometry that I have ever read: it is strikingly innovative and really enjoyable (also, it does not require a particularly advanced background).

From the book description:

> New Horizons in Geometry represents the fruits of 15 years of work in
>   geometry by a remarkable team of prize-winning authors—Tom Apostol and
>   Mamikon Mnatsakanian. It serves as a capstone to an amazing
>   collaboration. Apostol and Mamikon provide fresh and powerful insights
>   into geometry that requires only a modest background in mathematics.
>   Using new and intuitively rich methods, they give beautifully
>   illustrated proofs of results, the majority of which are new, and
>   frequently develop extensions of familiar theorems that are often
>   surprising and sometimes astounding. It is mathematical exposition of
>   the highest order.
>
> The hundreds of full color illustrations by Mamikon are visually
>   enticing and provide great motivation to read further and savor the
>   wonderful results. Lengths, areas, and volumes of curves, surfaces,
>   and solids are explored from a visually captivating perspective. It is
>   an understatement to say that Apostol and Mamikon have breathed new
>   life into geometry.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! This is really appropriate! :)

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I'll recommend [Geometry Revisited](http://www.maa.org/publications/ebooks/geometry-revisited) by H. S. M. Coxeter and S. L. Greitzer.

Answer (score 1):

Green Lion Press's:

- [*Euclid's Elements: All Thirteen Books in One Volume*](http://greenlion.com/books/EuclidsElements.html)

or

- [*The Bones: A handy where-to-find-it pocket reference companion to Euclid's Elements*](http://greenlion.com/books/TheBones.html)

The latter is very unique; it's all the propositions and diagrams, but without the detailed proofs.

Answer (score 1):

Another very nice book is [Indra's pearls The vision of Felix Klein](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IE6MP7S) with a [preview at google](http://books.google.com/books?id=kC5kdUirHHoC&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: Avatamsaka Sutra

Comment: Yeah @Andrew Of course you knew the Hua-yen Sutra with a nice illustration [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=kC5kdUirHHoC&pg=PR18). Cheers!